# Need to Update a column randomly. But the random Values are enumerated

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a set of values (not continous) in a TableB(id)

I need to update a column in TableA with these values randomly.

Will this query do what I want?

```
update TableA set column1 = (select id from TableB order by rand() limit 1)
```

Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: What are the current values in `Column1` of `TableA` ?  The problem I see with your current approach is that you might end up using the same value twice.

Comment: Your current query will set all `column1` fields in all rows in `TableA` to the same, randomly selected `id` value from `TableB`. It's not clear if that's what you want - please clarify.

Comment: Thanks @Synchro I am Using Mysql. So it runs fine. It doesn't populate same Values.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: It is fine to have repeated Values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning your proposed statement:

```
update TableA set column1 = (select id from TableB order by rand() limit 1)
```

Its behaviour is a bit unpredictable. I expected it to only run the sub-query once, and then update all rows of `TableA` with the value it came up with, but apparently MySql *does* run the sub-query for each record of `tableA`.

However, you will still get some values of `TableB` assigned to several rows of `TableA`. If you don't want this to happen, it becomes more complicated.

If your `TableA` has a unique `id` field, I would suggest this:

```
update     TableA 
inner join (select id, @rnA := @rnA + 1 as rnA
            from   TableA, 
                   (select @rnA := 0) init
           ) orderA
        on TableA.id = orderA.id   
inner join (select id, @rnB := @rnB + 1 as rnB
            from   (select * from TableB order by rand()) randB, 
                   (select @rnB := 0) init
           ) orderB
        on rnB = rnA          
set        TableA.column1 = orderB.id;
```

The two sub-selects `orderA` and `orderB` add an extra column: `rnA` and `rnB`, which are sequential order numbers starting at 1.

The join condition requires that these two are equal. This will make one record to be matched with at most one record from `TableA`. As `TableB` was first reordered in random order, the result will be what you could expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot  @trincot